# Create GUI depending on input arguments

Tags: matlab, user-interface

is it possible to create a GUI depending on its input arguments?
For example I'd like to call a GUI with my_gui(n) and the GUI appears with n ui-controls of style 'pushbutton' one below the other and each pushbutton has an separate callback. Whereas n can be any nomber from 1 to 20.
Is this somehow possilbe using eval?
Or does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks for your effort

Rafael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course its possible, for example:

```
function myGui(n)
   if nargin == 0; n = randi(20); end
   if n > 20 || n < 1
     error ( 'myGui:n', 'The input parameter "n" (%i) is outwith the allowed range (0 to 20)', n );
   end
   % create the parent figure
   hFig = figure;
   % create the positions
   locations = linspace ( 0.9, 0.1, n );
   % loop for n to create them, in this example the callback displays the number of the button pushed.
   % The buttons have a fixed height of 0.05 (normalized).
   for ii=1:n
     uicontrol ( 'parent', hFig, 'style', 'push', 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0.1 locations(ii) 0.5 0.05], 'String', num2str(ii), 'Callback', @(a,b)fprintf ( 'Pushed %i\n', ii ) );
   end
 end
```

Comment: Wow. This was fast and accurate. Thanks alot, this works great